# Django How to give 2 field names in filters.py date filter

Tags: python, django, datefilter

In filters.py
Here i want to give 2 field names in start date

```
class enquiryFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    start_date = DateFilter(field_name="updated_at", lookup_expr='gte',label='From',widget=DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date','id':'start_date'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The two fields are date field using 'and', 'or' conditions we can give 2 field names in one filter

```
class enquiryFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    start_date = DateFilter(field_name="updated_at" and "created_at", lookup_expr='gte',label='From',widget=DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date','id':'start_date'}))
```